# Decrypt and OpenSSL encrypted file

Tags: .net, encryption, openssl

I'm trying to make an application on visual studio 2013 to perform the following linux command line task:

> openssl enc -aes-192-cbc -d -nosalt -nopad -bufsize 16384 -in $file -K $aeskey  -iv $invec

I've read about openssl.net, but I can't get it work on my project (nuget errors due to framework version no matter the framework version I choose), so I've tried built in .NET libraries, but I don't know if I'm using the right ones. I'm a noob on encryption protocols and I've managed to do this:

```
Dim decypted As String
Dim rcsp As Rijndael
Dim fStream As IO.MemoryStream
Dim output As Byte()
Dim stream As CryptoStream

rcsp = Rijndael.Create()
rcsp.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sKey) <---- ERROR HERE ---->
rcsp.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sIV)

output = Convert.FromBase64String(sFileToDecrypt)
fStream = New IO.MemoryStream(output)
stream = New CryptoStream(fStream, rcsp.CreateDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
```

The error I'm getting (translated from spanish) is something like: "the specified key does not have the valid size for this algorithm" on the line marked with the error.

My keys sizes are 24 bytes for the key and 32 bytes the initialisation vector; both hexadecimal.

Comment: Note that this encryption is unrelated to the SSL protocol. It just happens to be implemented in the OpenSSL program.

Comment: Thanks, @CodesInChaos! Surely that's the reason why the things I've read about SSL seems nothing to do with the thing I need to do and I've ended up asking here. However I still don't know how to do it...